# How to implement multiprocessing in so the output can be saved to a database?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
def update_all():
    max = 100
    item_list = [r['item'] for r in db]
    for i in range(len(item_list)):
        item= item_list[i]
        data = pricer(item, max)
        db.update(data, Search.item == item)
```

The above function when called, updates the price of all items in a database. It takes around 1 or 2 seconds to price one item and there are 1000 of items, so I was thinking of using multiprocessing or multithreading whichever will work best for this scenario to do this stuff quickly.
Any idea on how to implement it to the above function? I tried it myself but couldn't figure it. Any help would be greatful

Comment: Think about splitting `for loop` into chunks and let each `thread` to do his job. It depends on `db` type and etc, you didn't detail much. Also, `max` is not a good name for variable since it's a built-in function in `python`.

Comment: concurrent.futures is a nice api, it handles a lot of the work for you. There are a number of examples in the documentation - one particular [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) shows how to make numerous *concurrent* url requests. This is similar to what you want to do - make numerous DB updates. You should [profile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) your process to see where the bottleneck actually is before you start down the concurrency path - you need to know what to *parallelize*.

Comment: @Hook I m using TinyDB and I just edited the original variable to 'max' in this post.

Comment: @wwii Thank I will go through it.